# avoiding eclipse "changed on file system" dialog?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a preference or tweak that will stop Eclipse from putting up a dialog "This file has been changed on the file system." when I switch to Eclipse from another editor?

Steps:

- open eclipse project
- edit some file and save it (page is now 'clean' but has been touched previously)
- switch to other editor
- edit same file
- switch back to eclipse
- see dialog

Comment: What behaviour do you want instead? both the alternatives (re-load and mutate the buffer without asking; or carry on as if the file hasn't been altered externally) seem like the wrong thing to do IMO, so I don't know which one you want.

Comment: reload buffer from file system--the default choice offered by the dialog.  my use-case is that I'm the one switching editors, so I'm sure that the file system is correct.

Comment: Keep in mind, this dialog comes up even when the buffer is 'clean': there is no change made by the Eclipse editor that hasn't been saved to disk. The page is clean. Then switch to another editor, touch file, and return to Eclipse.  Eclipse sees a changed file system and complains.  If it were complaining because of a *dirty* page that hadn't been saved, and only existed in RAM, that would be different.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Maybe telling Eclipse to refresh the workspace automatically helps:

> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh automatically

Comment: fixed with at least Indigo build 20110615-0604; perhaps fixed beforehand.  The prefs changed names, now:  "Refresh on access"  and "Refresh using native hooks or polling"

Comment: @larham1 Which one disables *changed on filesystem* dialog?

Comment: additionally to "Refresh on access" and "Refresh using native hooks or polling" also "Refresh on Access" is needed.

Comment: @alehro *additionally to "Refresh on access" (...) also "Refresh on Access" is needed* Didn't you misspell something here?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost, may be I did. I hadn't been using Eclipse already for a year.

Comment: This is already checked in my preferences, yet the "out of sync" error still occurs sometimes.

Comment: Same here---Eclipse Mars, both "Refresh using native hooks or polling" and "Refresh on access" are unchecked, but I still get the file change dialogs.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me using Indigo Service Release 1, Build id: 20110916-0149, with Preferences->General->Workspace->"Refresh Using Native Hooks or Polling" and "Refresh on Access" checked.

@Piotr Dobrogost, only one of these options is needed to get rid of the dialog prompt, however it depends on what behavior you want. They do different things, but each on its own prevents the dialog. With "Refresh Using Native Hooks or Polling", the file will automatically update when the file changes without user intervention. With "Refresh on Access", the file updates only when the context changes to the editor containing the changing file. For my purposes (watching script output change), I find "Refresh Using Native Hooks or Polling" by itself the most useful.

Also, this may seem obvious, but note that this only works for files ***in the eclipse workspace***.

Comment: FYI re. "that this only works for files in the eclipse workspace" I've just opened "https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506960.