# publishing failed with multiple errors eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat

I clean and restarted Tomcat Server.
From that time the error comes as follows

Publishing failed with multiple errors
Resource is out of sync with the file system

Can you help me to avoid.

T.Saravanan

Comment: Can you please provide the error message you receive?

Answer (score 63):

> Resource is out of sync with the file system

Eclipse produces this message when a file in an Eclipse project is changed outside of Eclipse. To avoid it:

- a) Don't change files outside of Eclipse
- b) Refresh the workspace/project after changing files outside of Eclipse <kbd>F5</kbd> or
- c) Enable `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Refresh Automatically`

Note: in STS 2.8.1, it is "Refresh on Access"

Answer (score 14):

For maven project :
Open Run as => run configurations,
Select the good target "Maven build", 
Select the tab Refresh,
Select "Refresh ressources upon completion", select "The selected resource" and apply.

Now you can run the tomcat server after running the targeted maven build and it's works.

Answer (score 12):

If all of the above is not working just try below

right click on the project -> Close Project

then again

right click on the project -> Open Project

Then try to build and restart the server, hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem just clean the project and rebuilt the same and it worked for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh project , it will work , if it does not then close and open eclipse again .This should be corrected

Answer (score 0):

The issue because the project is not refreshed in the workspace.

1.Right-click on the project in the workspace
2.Clean Tomcat working directory if required 
3.Restart the server

and the server should start again.

[avoiding "resource is out of sync with the filesystem"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343735/avoiding-resource-is-out-of-sync-with-the-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows:

- make sure you do not have windows open with your deployment location.
- This may prevent Eclipse from being able to delete the webapp and republishing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the server and re-configure the server

step1: go to server tab

step2: right click on your server and select delete option

step3: now you will get no servers found

step4: re-configure the server