# incorrect config.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

What is incorrect in my `config.xml` file for tomcat 7.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
   <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
   <Manager pathname="" />
   <Resource name="jdbc/mkyongdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="user" password="12345" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mkyongdb"/>
</Context>
```

An error occurs when I`m publishing the application on the server:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\Tomcat v7.0
>   Server at      localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or
>   incomplete. Resource is out of sync with the file system:
>   `/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at      localhost-config/context.xml`.

But now this error occurs:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at `\Servers\Tomcat v7.0`
>   Server at `localhost-config`. The configuration may be corrupt or
>   incomplete. Element type "Resource" must be followed by either
>   attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: Do you mean context.xml? If so please edit your question and title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse?  If so, perhaps this question might be helpful:

[publishing failed with multiple errors eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618652/publishing-failed-with-multiple-errors-eclipse)

If you're not using Eclipse let me know and I'll delete my answer :)

Comment: the question should be flagged as a duplicate now to the question you linked

Answer (score -1):

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\Tomcat v7.0
>   Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or
>   incomplete. Element type "Resource" must be followed by either
>   attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

if you want to run your program without any error, change your workspace with different name and again develop and deploy your  application  i am sure it will run ..........

Comment: No explanation as to why this will work.