# Tomcat Server fails to start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

**Problem:**

When I try to add following code to context.xml of Tomcat 7 It gives this error.

(NOTE: I'm adding this code from inside the Eclipse)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Resource
    name="jdbc/UsersDB"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="30"
    maxWait="10000"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersDB"
    username="root"
    password="secret"
/>
</Context>
```

**Error:**

**Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
Element type "Resource" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"**.

And when I remove this code and save context.xml , Server starts **successfully** without doing anything (Refreshing and all).

**What I have tried:**

Referred This question:
[publishing failed with multiple errors eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618652/publishing-failed-with-multiple-errors-eclipse)

- Tried closing Eclipse and opening again.
- Tried closing and opening peoject again.

Nothing is working.

What should I try Now?

**UPDATE:**

Tomcat server started successfully. I just typed everything in context.xml rather than copy paste the code. It could be some encoding problem I guess in copy pasting the code directly into eclipse file.

Comment: can you post the whole context.xml here

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look . Resource should be properly enclosed within the Context. Like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/webAppName">

  <Resource
    name="jdbc/UsersDB"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="30"
    maxWait="10000"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersDB"
    username="root"
    password="secret" />

    </Context>
```

Comment: Edited my question.. It shows whole code in context.xml

Comment: Actually the same code works very well on my other computer.
I tried making the whole project on my desktop pc and this is happening...

Comment: It should be " </Context> " at the end not </context>. Check If this is the issue in your code .

Comment: Sorry, It is already </Context> and not </context>. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar thing working. All the difference - I have one single row, not multiple lines like you have. Try it in a single row. Plus before you copy it to eclipse, try copy it to notepad, or another simple editor to remove invalid chars.

Comment: This same thing is working on my laptop and denying to work on my PC.
and just this problem is occured. everything else shows no error.

Comment: It is possible, that you saved this file with some different encoding. It may depend on tools, that you used to copy-paste the file content or the way you saved the file. I suggest to ensure, that you save file in ASCII format.
Open it with notepad, instead of eclipse and save it as ascii file.

Comment: I don't know where that file is located in my PC because the directory I provided for the tomcat server was not changed when I make change inside eclipse. So I suppose eclipse make his own copy of the server and I don't know where it is. I thought this could be the problem so I just manually typed everything rather than copy paste it, and It worked!
Thanks for your reply :D