# Tomcat & Maven: "Publishing failed with multiple errors Error reading file"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I got a new problem with tomcat (maven and eclipse neon).

I didn't changed anything, just tried to start the server as always, but now tomcat gives me the "Publishing failed with multiple errors Error reading file". I looked up for theses files (it's 3 .jar files) and they are on the right place (in the .m2 folder, so in the maven repositories) but with the file-ending ".lastUpdated". I removed the .lastUpdated but it didn't work. It seems to be something with the .lastUpdated-Thing. Also which might be interesting for solving: i have various versions of this .jar's and the older versions don't have this .lastUpdated thingy.

*Things i have already done:*

```
Clean Tomcat, Clean Project etc.
Eclipse Clean Startup
Eclipse started as administrator
Maven -> Update Project
Checked settings.xml
Refreshed the workspaced multiple times
Manualley build the workspace
Git pull to get the newest version
```

The maven repositories come from a company-intern server.

Thanks!

Comment: try these "Enable Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Refresh Automatically" , if not ok could you pls submit fullstacktrace?

Comment: No it didnt work. There is no fullstacktrace, just "Publishing failed with multiple errors Error reading file" and than the file-names (which I cannot post here, sorry)

Comment: check Isaac Truett answer and follow it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618652/publishing-failed-with-multiple-errors-eclipse

Comment: Also didn't work. Temporally fixed the problem I think. I changed in the POM the depencies into the older versions which seems to work. But it's not a good solution so I would be pleased if someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the project related repositories from the .m2 directory and update the maven project. 
Rebuild your project then. 
This seems to be an error with the dependency resolution.