# Disable the building of one project in an Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, build, performance

I have a workspace with some projects of mine and a really big project, which takes two hours to be built. I would like to disable the automatic building of this wide project while maintaining the build enabled for the other projects. Is that possible? How would I do it? Is there other options to solve my problem.

Comment: You're asking for a workaround to what sounds like a problematic project structure. Either you don't change the code so the big project doesn't build or you end up compiling against an out-of-date project.

Comment: @SteveD in fact, my big project is the Liferay source code, which is never directly updated, so the case is like you said: the project will never be changed. Nonetheless, you have a point: the structure of this project is not optimal. I will ask a question about how Liferay developers deal with problem, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "close" the project (right-click "Close Project"); that stops Eclipse from looking at it altogether.

Alternatively, in the project properties, under the "Builders" tab, you could uncheck "Java Builder". I think this would turn off compiling and (most?) error checking.

Comment: That does not solve my problem, unfortunately. I need to frequently read and copy code from this large project so I cannot close it.