# resource is out of sync in eclipse with the file system

Tags: android

I am getting the following error whenever i try to open the project.properties file of my project :- Could not open the editor: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Myproject/project.properties'.

Comment: If the file is open in the editor, it might be out of date. Try reloading the file.

Comment: just close the file, clean your project and restart eclipse, works for me everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace

in workspace: make sure the first and second option are checked:

1) Build automatically

2) Refresh using native hooks or polling

[image]

**Just right click on the project in the Package Explorer view and select Refresh. It works**

Comment: i have checked both options but still getting same error.

Comment: @Shikha: you have to use the latest version.

Comment: This will reduce your problem. just right click on the project in the Package Explorer view and select Refresh.

Comment: after refereshing getting this error again    error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Comment: add appcompat_v7 support library into your project and than check.

Comment: After adding appcompact i am going to add library doesnot show to add

Comment: If you just right click of the project and than select properties and than select Android, inside this view you can add that library, it is very simple.

Comment: Its done by creating a new workspace .Finally its done.

Comment: If this answer helpful to you, please accept it and upvote it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using android studio. It is THE official IDE. Eclipse community for android is deprecating at a faster rate. Any ways to resolve your issue checkout this **link**

> [avoiding "resource is out of sync with the filesystem"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343735/avoiding-resource-is-out-of-sync-with-the-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project in the package explorer view and select "refresh" or just select the project and press F5.