# .project is out of sync with the file system Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting below issue in eclipse project

> Could not set the project description for 'web-portal' because the
>   project description file (.project) is out of sync with the file
>   system.

I tried below things

1. Build whole workspace again and again
2. Right Click on project->Refresh
3. Run `mvn -U eclipse:eclipse`
4. Refresh whole workplace

But issue is not going to resolve. Can anyone suggest How to resolve this issue?

**EDIT:-**

Whoever mentioned this question as a duplicate please at please read the content of the question Whatever solution provided in the link its not a proper solution and also its not going to resolve the problem .

[image]

While i already checked the option given lots of places

[image]

Comment: You might be able to find your answer in this similar thread: [avoiding "resource is out of sync with the filesystem"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343735/avoiding-resource-is-out-of-sync-with-the-filesystem)

Comment: @nbokmans That i already read and tried also mentioned in my question as well.

Comment: Whoever mark this question as a duplicate please read the question first

Comment: I have read your question, and I have also read the thread I linked in the comments. There are multiple solutions in that thread that you haven't tried yet, according to this thread.

Comment: @nbokmans There is no difference between resource and .class-path ?

Comment: Create a new project and copy the meta files .project, .classpath etc to ur old project and clean the project . Give F5 in the project explorer

Comment: @madhairsilence How it will work ? By copying the files from another project?

Comment: just delete target folder in your workspace  then run mvn command

Comment: @Himanshu Delete target folder will not help because .classpath not exist in target folder

Comment: @Subodh Joshi try to delete the .project, .classpath and .settings then change the workplace and re-open the project using eclipse

Comment: is it multi module project?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi See .project is just a reference file.. u can replace and once u open ur project and sync, it will overwrite it

Answer (score 20):

For me closing and opening project worked.

Comment: This is the quickest workaround I've found also. (I get the issue in Gradle / Buildship, usually after switching branches.)

Comment: I've encountered the same problem after I have edited a file using another IDE. I've tried cleaning the project and rebuild it a few times. But after restarting recipes the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

ALT+F5 will do the work, or just go to:
Right click on project folder -> Maven -> Update project

Hope that helps!