# Causes for "resource is out of sync with the filesystem" error

Tags: java, eclipse

I was working on a project in eclipse and everything was working fine, but when i came back the next day I got an error: `resource is out of sync with the filesystem`. I found out the solution was refreshing everything and that fixed my problem, but i'm curious to how the resources get out of sync in the first place and also what it even really means for resources to be out of sync with the filesystem.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343735/avoiding-resource-is-out-of-sync-with-the-filesystem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file was modified, but not through Eclipse.

For performance, Eclipse caches information about files, and Eclipse will of course update the cache when it modifies a file, but if the file is modified by another process, the cache is out of sync with the actual file, so it requires a refresh.